# VBA: divide table into 3 groups and compare time (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with 3 groups (defined by values '1G, 3G or 5G' in column B) as shown below.

For every time (column A) of value 1G, I need to test if a value 3G appears within 10 minutes (shown in column A) of 1G. If so, then I need to test if a value 5G appears within 20 minutes (of time for value 1G).

So read time '1G' then read time '3G' and if =< 10 minutes, then read time '5G' =< 20 minutes.

```
'Time'    'Group Name'  'Data'
----------
12:08 am       1G        747
12:45 am       1G        745
1:00 am        1G        746
12:36 am       3G        743
12:45 am       3G        747
1:03 am        3G        74
12:50 am       5G        75
1:00 am        5G        741
```

Format 'Time': 9/25/2012 8:37:00 pm

I'm looking to write the result on a new sheet with all data per row.

I have looked at answers on this site and others, but not found answers.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: do the data numbers have to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This macro will extract all 1G line that have a 3G within 10 minutes, and a 5G within 20.

```
   Sub Macro2()
Dim lLastRow As Long, shtOrg As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet, rgLoop As Range

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Set shtOrg = ActiveSheet
Set shtDest = Sheets.Add

lLastRow = shtOrg.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

shtOrg.Range("D2:D" & lLastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-2]=""1G"",IF(COUNTIFS(C[-3],"">="" &RC[-3],C[-3],""<=""&RC[-3]+10/1440,C[-2],""3G"")*COUNTIFS(C[-3],"">="" &RC[-3],C[-3],""<=""&RC[-3]+20/1440,C[-2],""5G"")>0,TRUE,""""),"""")"
shtOrg.Range("E2:E" & lLastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=N(IF(RC[-3]=""3G"",COUNTIFS(C[-1],TRUE,C[-4],""<=""&RC[-4],C[-4],"">=""&RC[-4]-10/1440),IF(RC[-3]=""5G"",COUNTIFS(C[-1],TRUE,C[-4],""<=""&RC[-4],C[-4],"">=""&RC[-4]-20/1440),"""")))>0"

shtOrg.Range("A1:E" & lLastRow).AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="TRUE"

shtOrg.Range("A1:C" & lLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy shtDest.Cells(1, 1)

shtOrg.Range("A1:E" & lLastRow).AutoFilter
shtOrg.Range("A1:E" & lLastRow).AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="TRUE"
shtOrg.Range("A2:C" & lLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

shtOrg.Columns("D:E").ClearContents
shtOrg.Range("A1:E" & lLastRow).AutoFilter


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is it possible to write also the corresponding '3G' and '5G' rows in the time sequence in shtDest?

Comment: can the time between the 3G and 5G be anything between 1 second and 19:59? Can the 5G occur before the 3G?

Comment: Yes, and also = 0 as is once the case, and = 20. If 5G occurs between 1G and 3G, that is also valid.

Comment: This is indeed what I've been trying to get to! I'm looking at how to change the order. I'd put it in order of time, so according to column A first and second per group in column B. How can I modify that order?

Comment: you can just record a sort macro and use it on the shtdest sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula in your first row of data (I've assumed row 2):

```
=AND(B2="1G",SUM((B3:$B$8="3G")*(A3:$A$8<=A2+"00:10")*(A3:$A$8>=A2)),SUM((B3:$B$8="5G")*(A3:$A$8<=A2+"00:20")*(A3:$A$8>=A2)))
```

Change the $B$8 and $A$8 in the formula to your last row of data.

***After entering the formula, instead of pressing `Enter`, press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`***. Curly brackets should appear around your formula.

Now drag the formula down. Anything that evaluates true has matched your conditions. It only searches below the current position, so best to order your data.

Now use an autofilter to get the relevant rows. If I understand correctly you can use a pivottable on another sheet, but I have no idea how that's done :)

Comment: Of course, you probably won't care much for this solution, now that you have one working, I really just wanted to point out that filtering data can often be done without VBA.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion mkingston! I will take a close look at it, and see how fast this is (I work with a dynamic table and more columns). I may possibly like the sorting to happen within the vba script.